# Finding difference in days

Tags: date-time, timestamp

I want to store the current time using the update_option and then compare it if the set time was 3 days ago. I want to know in what `format` I should store the time? and then how can I compare it with current time and find the difference in the days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the time as a unix time stamp then you can use [human_time_diff](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) to compare.

`echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );`

If the difference is more than 24 hours difference it will return the value in days.

Comment: I'm using this but it's showing me an extra 8 hours... you wouldn't know what's causing that would you?

Comment: FIXED: echo human_time_diff(get_the_modified_date('U'), current_time( 'timestamp', 1 )) . ' ago';